# Having problem trying to install psycopg2 on Windows 10

Tags: python, psycopg2

I am using GIT to run the following command

```
$ python -m easy_install psycopg2-2.6.2.win32-py3.5-pg9.5.3-release.exe
```

When I do that I am running into this error

```py
File "C:\Users\Nancy\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-z6mcndcr\psycopg2-2.6.2-py3.8-win32.egg.tmp\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 104
    connection_factory=None, cursor_factory=None, async=False, **kwargs):
                                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

  File "C:\Users\Nancy\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-z6mcndcr\psycopg2-2.6.2-py3.8-win32.egg.tmp\psycopg2\tests\test_async.py", line 58
    self.conn = self.connect(async=True)
```

Can someone please help? Newbie here 
Thanks a lot

Comment: For Windows, I usually download binary versions of packages as `.whl` and then pip install. See [`psycopg2`](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#psycopg)

Answer (score 0):

psycopg 2.6 doesn't support Python 3.5 or whatever version `async` became a keyword.

Please install the library from PyPI using `python -m pip psycopg2` or building will likely fail.

Comment: Should I uninstall the previous version of psycopg 2.6?